# Get Send Classifications using FuelSDK-PHP

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to get a list of acceptable Send Classification's using Exact Target's SOAP API.

Our use case is that a user in a HubExchange app will be creating a TriggeredSend, and they will select the Send Classification from whatever they already have set up in their ET account.

We're currently using [FuelSDK-PHP](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-PHP) to integrate the SOAP API with our system, but we don't have any issues with adding other dependencies or using PHP's SOAP Client.

I see [other](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31765/email-send-definition-using-data-filtered-data-extension) [people](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/26974/need-help-with-exception-failure-when-scheduling-a-send-via-soap-api-in-php) creating `ExactTarget_SendClassification`s in their code, but there isn't much explanation of what's behind that. I also found [this](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_send_classification/), and [this](https://github.com/MichaelAllenClark/exacttarget-soap-php/blob/master/exacttarget_soap_client.php#L1659), but that only seems to cover creating Send Classifications.

Is there a way to just poll the user's account to see what Send Classifications are available?

Comment: I wanted to add the tag `send-classification`, but I don't have enough points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not done this with the SDK, but I do know it works with SOAP (which FUEL is wrapping).  This soap envelop will get all send classifications.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com"> {***Replace this with OAUTH token****}  </fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <!--Retrieve all the send classification-->
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>SendClassification    </ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID    </Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID    </Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey    </Properties>
            <Properties>Name    </Properties>
            <Properties>SendClassificationType    </Properties>
            <Properties>Description    </Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey    </Properties>
            <Properties>SenderProfile.CustomerKey    </Properties>
            <Properties>SenderProfile.ObjectID    </Properties>
            <Properties>DeliveryProfile.CustomerKey    </Properties>
            <Properties>DeliveryProfile.ObjectID    </Properties>
            <Properties>ArchiveEmail    </Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```